# I'm attempting to link a Master sheet with a Google Form for clock in/out hours. How would I do this?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-online

I'm attempting to add hours to each person by having them submit a Google Form, which will display their ID and time logged into a linked sheet(This is done). I then need the hours to be filtered by ID and then transferred over to the master sheet, so that their hours will come up next to their name/ID, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.  Use **Insert > Note** to describe what you want in the spreadsheet. You specify Google Forms in the question, but also list tags for Microsoft Excel — please edit the tags to make clear which platform you require.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have one spreadsheet.

- Your form submissions are recorded on sheet = "Form responses 1"
- You have a second sheet (say it's called "analysis") where you want to analyse the data.

Insert this formula in cell A1 of sheet="analysis"

`=query('Form responses 1'!A1:D9,"select B, C, D order by B")`

---

**Sample data**

[image: sample data]

---

**Employee analysis**

### [image: analysis]